# Why doesn't terminal show color schema once logged as root?

Tags: bash, shell, root, colors

I'm currently using Debian 7 Wheezy, and I've noticed that the **colors palette** on terminal (which might be useful to identify among a large set of files and folders) are not enabled once I log as root.

Same, I've noticed the **tab completion** doesn't work the same in this situation.

How can I configure these issues?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you log in as root, it uses roots  `~/.bashrc` file which is sourced every time you log in as root. In `~/.bashrc` file you'll find the following lines

```
# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
```

Uncomment these lines accordingly to get the desired result.

Once you've uncommented the lines you'll need to source .bashrc file e.g `source ~/.bashrc && ls -l /`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Could you explain me a little bit about the sourcing the `.bashrc` file thing?

Comment: @Diego This is been discussed in http://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Comment: @Diego You need to do that only if you've just modified the file. It's read automatically when bash starts.