# How do I reload ~/.dir_colors?

Tags: linux, terminal

I copied `/etc/DIR_COLORS` to `~/.dir_colors` because `/etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm` was being used and colours in `ls --color=auto` were too dark.

Now, how do I get this file to take effect immediately?  (i.e. Without restarting the shell?)

Is there something like what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> does for `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate. I've posted here a description.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86705/why-doesnt-terminal-show-color-schema-once-logged-as-root/86708#86708

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man dir_colors`:

> The  program  ls(1) uses the environment variable LS_COLORS to determine the colors in which the filenames are to be displayed.  This environment variable  is  usually set by a command like
>
> eval `dircolors some_path/dir_colors`

So you need to run `eval "$(dircolors ~/.dir_colors)"` now, and every time you launch a shell. The simplest way to do that is put the command in `~/.profile`